# How to checkboxes make changes to another page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, local-storage

I'm hanging around at the project I'm working on. The solution of this problem will make me very comfortable. I am working on two html files. (checkbox.html and color.html) There are two checkboxes in the checkbox.html file. When these two checkboxes are checked, the color of the div in color.html needs to change. (.example must be red.) This action must be registered with localStorage. So the color in color.html should not have changed, even if refresh the page. When the checkboxes are pressed back, the old color must be turned. (must be blue). I try everything. It's javascript code is hard? What should I add?

FILES:

**Color.html**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/script.js"></script>

<div class="example"> </div>
```

**Checkbox.html**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/script.js"></script>

   

        <div class="edit-container">
        <input type="checkbox" id="a1" />
        <input type="checkbox" id="a2" />
        </div>
```

**Script.js**

```js
$('.edit-container input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    var examplediv= document.getElementById("example")
    var container=$(this).parent('.edit-container');
    
    if(container.find('#a1:checked,#a2:checked').length==2)
       
        examplediv.css('background','red');
    else
         examplediv.css('background','');    
})
```

**Syle.css**

```css
.edit-container {width:100px; height:100px; background:green;}
.example {background:blue; width:200px; height:200px;}
```

jsfiddle files:
checkbox.html --> http://jsfiddle.net/3DPLd/62/
color.html --> https://jsfiddle.net/uumkbkwo/14/
I can not place the localStorage code, I apologize.

Comment: `localStorage.setItem("color", "red")` and `localStorage.getItem("color")`. And here's [documentation for localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). Wanna try on your own?

Comment: I actually tried localStorage everywhere. Thats because i can not place my code  :) I could not work anywhere. So actually anyway my problem is more important than localStorage. How does Checkbox affect another page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing certain operations on the second page based on the action of the first page. In your case, you should use `localStorage.setItem` and `localStorage.getItem` to get this done. This will store the color in storage as per the checkbox and you can retrieve them on any page.

[Read More here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Try below

```js
//This is inside the checkbox.html

$('.edit-container input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {

  var container = $(this).parent('.edit-container2').parent('.edit-container');

  if (container.find('#a1:checked,#a2:checked').length == 2) {
    localStorage.setItem('color', 'red')
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem('color', '')
  }
})

//This is inside the color.htmls

 $(document).ready(function() {
    let color = localStorage.getItem('color');

    $(".example").css('background', color);
 })
```

Comment: I tried but did not work. what am I missing? I tried this: https://jsfiddle.net/sp34pvzx/ and https://jsfiddle.net/9mk630y5/

Comment: now i add <a href="color.html">go-colorhtml</a> in checkbox.html because to see, did not work again.

Comment: You can not see this working in JSFiddle. Did you try that in your actual code?

Comment: I tried it, it did not work again. I left the comment for you to see. Am I missing something?

Comment: I have updated the answer, try that here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sp34pvzx/6/

Comment: thank you it's worked but problem this: When we check two checkboxes it turns red,it's okay, but when we check one or two of the checkboxes back, the old color should turn.  I mean the checkbox has to be pressed all the time to be red.

Comment: Thank you for your help and your time.